# Highcharts displaying improperly labeled data points

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm having an issue with highcharts displaying some of my datapoints with a duplicate label, then skipping subsequent labels, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

I gather from reading various posts that this is an issue with the PointInterval option; I'd like to set its value to 1 month, but since months a different lengths, this is not simple.

I am not sure of what a proper solution is though. Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/KJ3tk/

The graph is displaying January and March twice, and skipping February.

The solution suggested in this thread ( http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=17269 ) seems to be what I need, but I can't figure out how to implement it in the javascript that I currently have. This is the code that they suggest will fix the problem:

```
var data = [3,2,5,3,5,6,2,3,1];
var month = 4; // the first month
data = $.map(data, function(value) {
    return {
        x: Date.UTC(2000, month++, 1), 
        y: value
    };
});
```

I'd really appreciate any assistance! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     var mydata =  [   
 7418,7386,7552,8903,8439,9356,9861,9411,10257,10169,9622,9940,
                                    /*2009*/  
  10551,10326,12817,11739,11694,12209,12132,11842,11908,11909,11884,12450,
                                    /*2010*/    
15545,14495,16195,15064,13788,14452,14908,15858,16213,15994,15213,15651,
                                    /*2011*/    
17233,15515,19629,18960,19834,19997,19358,21042,20189,20660,20034,19815,
                                    /*2012*/   
22611,21435,23327,22876,22986,23692,21581,21832,22337
            ];
   var month = 0; // the first month
  mydata = $.map(mydata, function(value) {
    return {
      x: Date.UTC(2008, month++, 1), 
    y: value
}; });
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KJ3tk/1/)